# Detect first time user in Java application

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a sign-in and sign-up form just for practice. When the application runs for the first time, I would like the sign-up form to show first. How can I detect that the application is running for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is to check for the existence of a file. If it exists, then you know the application has been run before, otherwise you know that it has not run before, and so you create it.

```
File file = new File("some/path/filename.txt");
boolean firstRun = false;
if(!file.exists()){
    firstRun = true;
    file.createNewFile();
}
if(firstRun){
    // Code to run if it is the first time running the app
}else{
    // Code to run if it is not the first time running the app
}
```

In the future, this file could potentially be used for user configuration and such.

Comment: should i proceed with the code in "else" block?

Comment: @NelsonJohn See my update

Answer (score 1):

A sign up changes the state of your application. After it, there is a signed up user. So, what you might want is to check if there is a signed user. If you check for the first start, the user might exit the program without sign up and will never be asked for sign up on subsequent starts.

Comment: *"..the user might exit the program without sign up and will never be asked for sign up on subsequent starts."*  Good point.  That case needs to be accounted for.

Comment: @AndewThompson I have not much practise in writing english. Therefor I'm glad that you understood the problem I wanted to express. Thank you!